# Let there be a sequence such that the distance between two consecutive terms converges to 0. Must this sequence converge?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

I'm trying to solve the following analysis problem and I've developed a proof, I'm just not entirely sure if it's valid or not.

Let $\{a_n\}_n$ be a sequence such that $|a_n -a_{n+1}|\to 0$. Must $\{a_n\}_n$ converge? If so prove it, and if not, find a counterexample.

Proof:

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Since $|a_n -a_{n+1}| \to 0$, there exists $N\in \Bbb R$ such that$|a_n-a_{n+1}| \lt \frac {\epsilon}{m+n}$for all $n > N$. Then, for all $m,n > N$, we have 
    $$|a_m - a_n|= |a_m - a_{m-1} + a_{m-1} - a_{m-2} + ... + a_{n+1} - a_{n}| $$ $$\le |a_m - a_{m-1}| + |a_{m-1} - a_{m-2}|  + ... + |a_{n+1} - a_n|$$ $$ = \sum_{n}^{m - 1}{|a_{i+1}-a_{i}|} = \sum_{n}^{m - 1}{|a_{i}-a_{i+1}|}$$ $$ \lt \sum_n^{m-1} {\frac {\epsilon}{m+n}} = \frac{\epsilon\;(m+n)}{m+n}=\epsilon.$$
Therefore, the sequence is Cauchy and converges. $\Box$

Any help with checking/improving my proof would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Your choice of $N$ depends on $m$ and $n$; there may be no integers $n,m >N$!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy But isn't it always guaranteed that there is an integer greater than any given real number by the Archimedean Property?

Comment: What if $N$ happens to be $m+n$?

Comment: Ah, I think I see the issue. So when I'm doing a convergence type proof like this, can I only have my N depend on epsilon?

Comment: You got the point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$a_n=1+\frac 1 2+\cdots+\frac 1 n$ is a counterexample.